# asp.net mvc 4 : ajax call to a download controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this action performing a download here :

```
[HttpGet]
    public void Download(string FileName)
    {
        string FilePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Exe\\";

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ");
        response.TransmitFile(FilePath + FileName);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

in one of my views im doing an ajax call to this action like this:
    var options = {
            url: 'Home/Download?filename=' + file.Name + file.Extension,
            method: 'GET'
        };

```
    $.ajax(options)
    .done(function () {
        console.log('You successfully downloaded ' + file.Name);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('Something bad happened');
    });
```

when i build my project and navigate to /home/download?id=filename, all is working fine and nice: chrome starts downloading.
BUT when i do it using the ajax call above the `done` callback is called, so the download was successful, but i dont see the download in my browser(chrome) anywhere, and it doesnt ask me where to put this file. first, where is this file actually gone? why when i use the ajax call it behaves differently ?

Thanks for ur help.

P.S. : changing from 'get' to 'post' doesnt lead to a different result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with ajax.

Hovewer thera are plenty of tricks which could help you:

- redirecting whole page to download address,
- using for redirecting hidden iframe

Those two are methods to work with, you could also try using existing jquery plugins.

Comment: it makes sense. after rethinking it, with ajax it will never work.

Comment: i cant redirect, its supposed to be a SPA :)

Answer (score 0):

the browser will only treat the returning data as "data".
You can simply invoke the save dialog with a hidden iframe

```
<iframe id="#iframe" src="/home/download?id=filename"></iframe>

$('#download').click(function(){
  $('#iframe').attr('src','/home/download?id=newfilename');
}
```